# ML350 G5 Intel Xeon 5130 Server Dual Core and memory module of 4GB

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, memory, hp, hp-proliant

I want to buy `ML350 G5 Intel Xeon 5130 Server Dual Core 2GHz` which have `2GB ECC RAM`. I am .net developer and I want to setup server as my dev. server in my house.

On official page there is

```
Maximum (dual-core models): 16 GB (8 x 2 GB);
```

Does this means that I cannot use modules larger that 2GB (for example 1x2GB + 1x4GB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HP ProLiant ML350 G5](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04284193) server you're speaking of was introduced in 2005...

That's very old in technology terms. The chipset on that server only supports 2GB DIMMs, so the maximum RAM load is 16GB (8 slots x 2GB DIMMs).